# EmberJS and Handlerbars helpers in a CollectionView

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to use a collection view and in each item view use a handlerbars helper, but I can't get the helper function to expand my path into the value.

```
Ember.CollectionView.create({content: App.AController,
    itemViewClass: App.ItemView
});
Em.Handlebars.registerHelper('editable', function (path, options) {
    options.hash.valueBinding = path;
    return Em.Handlebars.helpers.view.call(this, App.EditField, options);
});
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="edit-field">
    {{#if isEditing}}
        {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding = "value" propagatesEvents = true}} 
    {{else}}
        {{#if value}}
            {{value}}
        {{else}}
            <span class="no-name">empty</span>
        {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="item-view">
    {{view.content.name}}
    {{editable view.content.name}}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/epigeon/dNqsV/29/ with full code example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'isEditing' property is on the view, but the context for the collectionView itemView is the content for that view. In order to refer to properties on the view in your template, you have to start the property path with 'view,' as in 'view.isEditing.'

I made that change in your fiddle and the example seems to work as I would expect.

Comment: this doesn't expand the value in "{{editable view.content.name}}" where does {{view.content.name}}.

Comment: Oh, silly me, the context isn't being set properly because your collectionview is originating as you manually instantiating a COllectionView and appending it.

Comment: As such the context is nonexistant (or in some cases getting set to 'window' which is totally not what we want.) try http://jsfiddle.net/dNqsV/32/ on for size.

Comment: Alternatively you could add     contextBinding: 'content' to your itemView

Comment: The idea of 'view preserves context' (an ancient toggleable option which is now the default) is that no matter how far down your go down your view heirarchy, unless you manually change the context of the view (using #with, for instance), it won't change. So, you should be able to, in theory, have a vew 3 or 4 deep in the hierarchy refer to and bind to the properties on the content property of an itemView just as if you were at the very top of the itemView view hierarchy. Of course, that is dependent on there being a proper context in the first place!

Comment: In that jsfiddle the editable field still has a value of empty instead of name like it should.

Comment: Gotcha. http://jsfiddle.net/dNqsV/33/. So, 'name' on the context is getting bound to 'value' on the view. I've updated the fiddle so that the edit field view's template refers to 'view.value' instead of just 'value.'